# Create key value javascript values

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to copy a simple example from here: https://via-profit.github.io/js-form-validator/
But I get 
`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':'`

`

```
var formHandle = document.querySelector('#myform'),
    options: { //ERROR REFERS TO THIS LINE

        // set a custom rule
        rules: {
            milk: function (value) {
                return (value.trim().toLowerCase() === 'milk');
            }
        },

        // set a incorrect message text
        messages: {
            en: {
                milk: {
                    incorrect: 'This is not a Milk ;-)'
                }
            }
        }
    };

// Got to validation
new Validator(formHandle, function (err, res) {
    return res;

}, options);`
```

Am i doing something super dumb here?
I copy and pasted there example.
What have I done wrong?

Comment: The example is wrong. What re you trying to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think documentation is wrong. It should be

```
var formHandle = document.querySelector('#myform');
var options = {

    // set a custom rule
    rules: {
...
```

Please try this. It will work.

Comment: Thank you. Annoying they provide an invalid example.

Answer (score 0):

may be it is the back tick at the end of your last line -> }, options);**`**